# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't see header files

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2017

I'm having an issue with the visibility of header files in my Windows Forms project (Visual Studio 2017).  I've included all header files in separate header file called "Header.h".  In the first file called "welcome.h", I want to call the next form as shown below...

```
beta::initial^ f = gcnew beta::initial();
this->Hide();
f->Show();
```

This is what I'm getting when I'm trying to compile it...

[image]

That doesn't actually makes sense to me since `initial` is the member of beta as shown in this screenshot...

[image]

This is how I include my header files in `Header.h`...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include "initial.h"
#include "welcome.h"
```

Every other header file contains...

```
#include "Header.h"
```

I also checked if every file is sure to be included in the project and everything is in the same folder.  What am I missing?

P.S. This is my first time posting here, so if my question isn't clear, then please guide me.

Comment: Is the circumflex `beta::initial^ f = gcnew beta::initial();` intended here? The syntax seems obscure, but I don't have experience with Windows Forms.

Comment: @nucleon it is C++/CLI syntax for a .Net garbage collectible reference allocated with `gcnew`. Those classes are declared as `ref class`.

Comment: Having a circular dependency between .h files is a very traditional problem.  Look in initial.h, make sure it doesn't #include welcome.h

Comment: Including the C++ algorithm header seems strange (are you *also* using standard containers?)

Comment: I have edited your Question to improve the presentation slightly.  Please note that if you wish to include an image in the body of your Question rather than a link to the image, then please use an `!` in front of the link details, i.e. here I have used `![][1]` and `![][2]`.  Note that the image description does not appear when you use this technique, which is why I have left the first set of brackets empty.

Comment: @crashmstr This is just part of my header file and yes, i've used standard containers at some point in my project

Comment: @Ðаn The more I use c++ in Windows Forms, more im sure that C# is so much better for that, but its too late for a change in this particular project. Thanks for advice.

Comment: @toonice That's what I was trying to do from the start. Thanks for that, truly helpful.

Comment: Sigh.  This chatter is very unhelpful and getting rather old.  It is a standard C++ problem, caused by the compiler using a single pass compilation model.  That does not suddenly change because you are using a syntax extension.  Other languages, like C# and VB.NET are more modern and take advantage of a compiler having access to a lot more memory.  They use a multi-pass compilation model that permits have a definition appear after usage.  Why ISO doesn't consider improving C++ is a bit odd, but they were never that good at making big changes.

Answer (score 0):

I just put an answer here:
[Style messed up after nuget update.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921652/style-messed-up-after-nuget-update/55796051#55796051)