# Style messed up after nuget update.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-4, nuget

I updated multiple nuget packages of default MVC application and my page style got messed up. Looks like partial styles are being loaded but I am unable to track down what went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

My Navbar before update.

[image: NavBefore]

My Navbar after update.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you'll have gone from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 during the update. There's quite a difference between the two, so you'll probably need to change a fair few of your Bootstrap classes. It's probably worth inspecting the page to find out which version is loaded.

Comment: @ObsidianAge thanks for suggesting this. I will try to revert to bootstrap 3.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I reverted bootstrap from 4 to 3 and all good now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear that.

I got the same problem, and it cost me a lot. So frustrating. Fortunately I found the solution.

It is because of the the new version of **Bootstrap**. To solve the problem, please follow the steps below:

1. Right click on your project, and go to "Manage NuGet Packages":

[image: Step 1]

2. Then find bootstrap, click on it. And you can see to the right the version selector. Click on the drop-down button:

[image: Step 2]

3. Then find an **older** version of bootstrap (**most likely, 3.3.7 will work for you**), and select it:

[image: Step 3]

4. Then click on the "Update" button:

[image: Step 4]

5. And then you can see that "bootstrap" has changed back to the old version you have selected:

[image: Step 5]

6. Then refresh you web page, and you can see it has returned to normal.

Don't repeat these steps if you don't have to.